# CGColorGetComponents always returns 0 CGColor (black)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to get the color of the background of a `UILabel`. I'm using this method:

```
- (UIColor *)colorOfPoint:(CGPoint)point{
   unsigned char pixel[4] = {0};
   CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
   CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixel, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

   CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -point.x, -point.y);

   [self.superview.layer renderInContext:context];

   CGContextRelease(context);
   CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
   UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:pixel[0]/255.0
                                 green:pixel[1]/255.0
                                  blue:pixel[2]/255.0
                                 alpha:pixel[3]/255.0];

   return color;
}
```

However, when I call `const CGFloat *componentColors = CGColorGetComponents([self colorOfPoint:self.amountLabel.frame.origin].CGColor);` in a subview of `UITableViewCell`, it always return 0 (aka black) for the background. How could that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

where are you running this code? 
inside a subclass on UILabel? 
I can't see why you call

```
[self.superView.layer renderInContext: ]
```

I suggest you change this to

```
[myLabel.layer renderInContext: ]
```

where myLabel is the pointer to the label you want the colour from.

Incidentally, have you tried myLabel.backgroundColor  ?

(the backgroundColor property is read/write, i.e. there is a getter there as well as a setter..)  the code you have for getting a colour from a specific point is good, but it seems overkill for a label, better suited to an image or something, unless you've filled it with a gradient or a pattern image this seems like a pretty expensive way to get the background colour..

Comment: Hmm altough I have to say that this makes sense it doesn't change much. I'm running this code in a subclass of `UITableViewCell`. Fact is that the result of the `color` keeps hitting `0 0 0 0`...